# How to change an NSButton's state with animation

Tags: cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite

I am trying to bind the state of a checkbox to a variable in my model. I want to update the state of the checkbox with the standard Yosemite animation (like when you click on it) when the corresponding boolean property in my model changes. Is there any method in NSButton that does this? I'm looking for something like `button.changeStateWithAnimation(NSOnState)`.

If you don't know what I mean by "standard Yosemite animations", be sure to check out [this video](http://damiaan.photos/files/buttonAnimations.m4v).

## What I tried

### Cocoa bindings

When I try to bind the button's value to my boolean property, the button updates when the model changes but without an animation.

### Without Cocoa bindings

So I tried to toggle the button's state programatically.

```
button.state = myStateProperty ? NSOnState : NSOffState
```

But this doesn't trigger the animation either.

The only way I could get it to work was to call NSButton's performClick like this:

```
let currentButtonState = button.state == NSOnState
if currentButtonState != myStateProperty {
    button.performClick(self)
}
```

But I think that's not the correct way of doing this. Is it?

Comment: I suspect that `performClick()` is your best bet, but you could try `button.animator.state = myStateProperty ? NSOnState : NSOffState`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your animator suggestion, I just tried `button.animator().state = state ? NSOnState : NSOffState` but it didn't work. Note that I had to write `()` after `animator` because it is a method.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to change the value of a checkbox with:

```
checkbox.animator().setNextState()
```

The checkbox flips between selected/deselected just fine, but without any animations.

So, I think the state is simply not an animatable property.

Your `performClick()` workaround may be the only thing possible here.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding code like this to your Bool variable declaration:

```
var checkBoxFlag:Bool = false
{
    didSet
    {
        if checkBoxFlag == true {myButton.state = NSOnState}
        if checkBoxFlag == false {myButton.state = NSOffState}
        myButton.display()
    }
}
```

The didSet code will get executed anytime the value of checkBoxFlag is changed.

Actually, you can do a lot more with this. For example if you have a Bool named resetAnimation:

```
var resetAnimation:Bool = false
    {
    willSet(newResetAnimation)
    {
```

("resetAnimation is about to be changed from (resetAnimation) to \    (newResetAnimation)")
        }
        didSet
        {
            if resetAnimation == true  {
                println("resetAnimation set to  (resetAnimation)")
            }else{
                println("resetAnimation set to  (resetAnimation)")
            }
        }
    }

If then in your code somewhere else you wrote:

```
resetAnimation = true
resetAnimation = false
resetAnimation = true
```

this would print:

> resetAnimation is about to be changed from false to true
>   resetAnimation set to  true
>   resetAnimation is about to be changed from true to false
>   resetAnimation set to  false
>   resetAnimation is about to be changed from false to true
>   resetAnimation set to  true

EDIT - Testing:

So here's the test scenario.  In the application I'm pasting this test into I have a status window with it's controller.  The window has a custom progress indicator.  I added an extraneous checkbox to the status window .xib file with a default state of on.

In the status window controller I declared

```
@IBOutlet var testCheckbox:NSButton!
```

and connected testCheckbox to the extraneous checkbox in the status window.

Then in the status window controller I declared an instance variable:

```
var checkBoxFlag:Bool = true
{
    didSet
    {
        if checkBoxFlag == true {testCheckbox.state = NSOnState}
        if checkBoxFlag == false {testCheckbox.state = NSOffState}
        testCheckbox.display()
    }
}
```

and in the status window controller function for updating the custom progress indicator the code is (note the break points):

```
func updateStatusProgress(statusprogress:CGFloat)
{
    println("In Update Status Before Change state = \(testCheckbox.state)");
    if checkBoxFlag == true // breakpoint 1 here
    {
        checkBoxFlag = false
    }else{
        checkBoxFlag = true
    }
    println("In Update Status After Change state = \(testCheckbox.state)");
    statusProgressIndicator.cgValue = statusprogress // Break point 2 here
    statusProgressIndicator.display()
}
```

Starting up the first pass at break point 1 printed:

In Update Status Before Change state = 1 and examining the window, the check box was checked.

At break point point 2 the application printed:

In Update Status After Change state = 0 and examining the window the check box was not checked

Further passes through yielded the same expected results.

I posted my code here just in case you can see some difference between this and your code about how this is implemented.

Comment: the problem is that setting myButton.state, is not causing the button to animate. I know I can use didSet and willSet, what I don't know is the method on NSButton to change its state with an animation.

Comment: OK, I added button.display(), but this still does not trigger the animation.

Comment: Hmmm...This should work, but I'll run some more tests.

Comment: It changes the state of the button, but without animation

Comment: I've edited my answer to give details about my testing.

Comment: have a look at this video to understand what I mean by animations: http://damiaan.photos/files/buttonAnimations.m4v

Comment: I looked at the video, and I get what you're trying to do.  The core issues are the same, however.  If you can just get the button's state to change and display the button as a function of it's  changed state, that's what you want.  BTW I don't like to leave issues unresolved, so be sure to update me on your progress.  I'm more than happy to give any assistance I can.

Comment: thank you for all your work. A solution that is working is the one with the `button.performClick(sender)`, I can't find any other methods on NSButton that trigger the animation. But I think this is not the cleanest solution and that there has to be a method that I don't know of.

Comment: stackoverflow has helped me greatly over time, and I only offer suggestions on this site as my way of giving back.  Sorry if I couldn't help.

Comment: `checkBoxFlag == true`? **You never test a bool against a bool value**; it is already a bool! `if checkBoxFlag == true` is the same as `if checkBoxFlag` and `if checkBoxFlag == false` is the same as `if !checkBoxFlag`.